# iOS app crashing after update

Tags: ios, core-data, crash

After updating the app from the AppStore, some of the users reported that the app can't start. It keep crashing one second right after start. Re installing the app fix the problem.

My app shares a coredata base with its today extension (Group sandbox). **Database has been correctly versioned**, I've successfully tried to update from each previous store version before submitting.

The struggle is that I can't reproduce the crash. The update went perfectly well on my 4 test devices (iPad, iPhone 5S, iPhone 4, iPhone 6+). iTunes connects and crashlytics don't report any crash.

In one of my previous apps, I got the same issue with a big process freezing the app for 20 seconds at start. But In this case, I do nothing special at start. I'm only instantiating my coredata context, GoogleAnalytics, Crashlytics and other light processing custom components.

I suspect the problem comes from the database. Power-users can have a heavy database file (more than 30MB). Do you think the Apple coredata migration process can exceed the app memory limit?

Comment: You can request a user to look at the general diagnostics section in the settings app and send you a copy of the log text which may give you a hint about the issue